# Object of type 'AttrList' is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

```
class SearchSuggest(View):
def get(self, request):
    key_words = request.GET.get('s','')
    re_datas = []
    if key_words:
        s = JobType.search()
        s = s.suggest('my_suggest', key_words, completion={
            "field":"suggest", "fuzzy":{
                "fuzziness":2
            },
            "size": 10
        })
        suggestions = s.execute_suggest()
        for match in suggestions.my_suggest[0].options:
            source = match._source
            re_datas.append(str(source["job_name"]))

    # return HttpResponse(json.dumps(re_datas), content_type="application/json")
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(re_datas), content_type="application/json")
    # re_datas=list(re_datas)
```

But the result :

[image: the result here]

So how can i fix this? thanks!I expect not list type!
I hope the view in the browser was the str but not list.I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Not nearly enough information here. What is AttrList? Where does it come from? What is returning these suggestions? What output do you actually want?

Comment: Ask yourself: how should [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) know how to serialize an object?

Comment: Do you always want the first array item?
if so - you can use: re_datas.append(str(source["job_name"][0]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try replacing `re_datas.append(source["job_name"])` with:

```
re_datas.append(str(source["job_name"]))
```

Looks like from your image that re_datas should basically be a list of strings. 
The problem is likely that source["job_name"] is returning an object that json does not understand how to serialize. If you just need the string representation of this object, try getting it with str(source["job_name"]). 
If it is more complex you will need to make your class json serializable - check out [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: This way is great, I'm new to program.Maybe sometimes I don't konw what's the key of the problem.Thanks! But It doesn't response the way i expect ,it response the list type .just like the above.However!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[ x for x in source["job_name"] ]
```

or

```
[ *source["job_name"] ]
```

`source['job_name']` (AttrList) can be iterated and stored in an array.

Comment: Please add some commentary